# Display string with incorrect format using RichTextBox

Tags: c#, formatting, richtextbox

I am doing some binary decoding of a `DataFormat`, and is trying to display the text in a `RichTextBox` in C#.

When looking at the variable in Visual studio the debugger shows this value 
`\u0005\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0?A\b\0building???=\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0"`
 but my `TextBox` only shows ``

How could I show an invalid `string` like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText` to `RichTextBoxStreamType.UnicodePlainText` to avoid the Invalid File format.